# Why are we checking context.connectionId when a recconect in signalR occurs?

Tags: .net, signalr, signalr-hub

As I know, The OnReconnected event handler in a SignalR Hub can execute directly after OnConnected but not after OnDisconnected for a given client. (source: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)

So, if onReconnected will never be happened after onDisconnected and context.connectionId will remain the same, why official example checks context.connectionId in user connections and add it if not exists.

Link: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            _connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);

            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
```

If disconnect occurs gracefully, stopCalled will be true. Otherwise, it will be false (timeout etc), but that doesn't mean signalr is disconnected for sure.

> If SignalR is behind a load balancer with scaleout configured, the
>   client may still be connected to another SignalR server.

Even client is not disconnected, `OnDisconnected(false)` can be fired. Then you remove `Context.ConnectionId`.

But if client is still connected, then reconnect will be fired. So that time you should check may be you removed this connection with `OnDisconnected(false)` which is not actual disconnect.